# How to loop conditions in do-while

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements, do-while

**Here is my code. I am trying to find different things for a triangle and I have a few conditions.**

I am new in c programming and I would like to know how I can loop these conditions. If, for example, the first condition is not met, then it displays the appropriate message and asks you to enter again and so on constantly until the entered numbers are correct.

```
do {  
    printf("Enter the first side of the triangle: ");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("Enter the second side of the triangle: ");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("Enter the third side of the triangle: ");
    scanf("%f", &c);

    if (a > (b+c)) {
        printf("Invalid value a");
    }
    else if (b > (a+c)) {
        printf("Invalid value b");
    }
    else if (c > (a+b)) {
        printf("Invalid value c");
    }
    else if (a < 0) {
        printf("The number a must be positive");
    }
    else if (b < 0) {
        printf("The number b must be positive");
    }
    else if (c < 0) {
        printf("The number c must be positive");
    } 
    else {
        perimeter = a + b + c;
        half_p = perimeter / 2;
        printf("\nPerimeter of triangle: %f\n", perimeter);

        height = ((2 * sqrt(half_p * (half_p - a) * (half_p - b) * (half_p - c))) / a);
        printf("\nHeight of triangle: %f\n", height);

        square = sqrt(half_p * (half_p - a) * (half_p - b) * (half_p - c));
        printf("\nSquare of triangle: %f\n", square);

        median = 0.5 * sqrt(2 * pow(b, 2) + 2 * pow(c, 2) - pow(a, 2));
        printf("\nMedian of triangle: %f\n", median);

        bisector = ((2 / (b + c))) * sqrt(b * c * half_p * (half_p - a));
        printf("\nBisector of triangle: %f\n", bisector);
    }
} while ()
```

I think I should add something here to make the program work perfectly, but I don't understand what. Thank you!

Comment: You're probably looking for the `break;` or more likely `continue;` statements.

Comment: You could use a variable to remember whether the values that you got are valid. Update that variable when you found out whether the input is valid or not. The use that variable in the while condition, to only loop when the input was invalid.

Comment: `} while ()` should have some condition as an exit criteria, i.e.   `bool running = True;`    ... `} while (running)`  When `running` is set to `False` (or `0`) the loop will exit.  Or a time duration... eg:  `} while (duration < 30)`  The argument of `while(argument)` will be either true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_Bool invalid = 1; //Assume invalid

do{
    printf("Enter the first side of the triangle: ");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("Enter the second side of the triangle: ");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("Enter the third side of the triangle: ");
    scanf("%f", &c);

    if (a > (b+c)) {
        printf("Invalid value a");
    }
    else if (b > (a+c)) {
        printf("Invalid value b");
    }
    else if (c > (a+b)) {
        printf("Invalid value c");
    }
    else if (a < 0) {
        printf("The number a must be positive");
    }
    else if (b < 0) {
        printf("The number b must be positive");
    }
    else if (c < 0) {
        printf("The number c must be positive");
    }
    else
      invalid = 0; //Change to valid if passes all tests

}while(invalid); //If invalid loop back to the scanf calls

//This stuff shouldn't happen until the input is valid so it should be outside the loop
perimeter = a + b + c;
half_p = perimeter / 2;
printf("\nPerimeter of triangle: %f\n", perimeter);

height = ((2 * sqrt(half_p * (half_p - a) * (half_p - b) * (half_p - c))) / a);
        printf("\nHeight of triangle: %f\n", height);

square = sqrt(half_p * (half_p - a) * (half_p - b) * (half_p - c));
printf("\nSquare of triangle: %f\n", square);

median = 0.5 * sqrt(2 * pow(b, 2) + 2 * pow(c, 2) - pow(a, 2));
printf("\nMedian of triangle: %f\n", median);

bisector = ((2 / (b + c))) * sqrt(b * c * half_p * (half_p - a));
printf("\nBisector of triangle: %f\n", bisector);
```

Comment: That's a useful answer to the question asked.  To add to it, I would suggest a few things.  Use just 1 scanf to read all three inputs, because it's more convenient for the user.  The messages are misleading; `a` is not too large necessarily, because b might be too small.  Reject invalid single values first, before computations.  Avoid negative flags; use `bool valid = false` and `while( ! valid )`.  Prefer `continue` to `else if` because the code is easier to read and understand.

Comment: I kept as much of OP's code as possible and reformatted only what was needed to solve the problem they were having. Perhaps this comment would be more helpful under the post rather than this answer. As to the negative vs positive flag and `continue` vs `else` preference, I will have to flatly disagree with you as to whether the alternative is easier to read and understand, as this is simply a matter of personal coding style

Comment: The important thing I wanted to say about this problem in my solution is which parts of the logic do and do not belong inside the loop. The loop should continue until the inputs are deemed valid, and then break. Loops in the form of `while(flag) if(condition) flag = 0;` are always preferable to loops in the form of `while(1) if(condition) break;` in my personal opinion. As to whether the flag represents a positive or negative concept is of little interest to me as long as its purpose is clear

Comment: yes, I like your answer because it answers the main question, i.e., when to exit the loop.  As to the rest, I would say all style questions are style questions.  I think I've learned a thing or two in almost 40 years of working with C, and offer my advice to the OP for his consideration.

Comment: I would argue that this particular question is a logic question, but even so, good style never goes unappreciated

Comment: It really helped me and the program works properly. I'll see what can be improved to make the user experience easy. Thanks again, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    
    float a,b,c;
    float median, perimeter, half_p, height, square, bisector;
do {  
    printf("Enter the first side of the triangle: ");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("Enter the second side of the triangle: ");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("Enter the third side of the triangle: ");
    scanf("%f", &c);

    if(a > (b+c)) {
        printf("Invalid value a");
        while(a > (b+c)){
              printf("Enter the first side of the triangle: ");
    scanf("%f", &a);  
        }
    }
    
    else if (b > (a+c)) {
        printf("Invalid value b");
                while(b > (a+c)){
    printf("Enter the second side of the triangle: ");
    scanf("%f", &b);
        }
    }

    else if (c > (a+b)) {
                while(c > (a+b)){
    printf("Enter the third side of the triangle: ");
    scanf("%f", &c);
        }    }

    else if (a < 0) {
        printf("The number a must be positive");
        while(a<0){
                printf("Enter the first side of the triangle: ");
    scanf("%f", &a);
        }
    }

    else if (b < 0) {
        printf("The number b must be positive");
                while(b<0){
                printf("Enter the second side of the triangle: ");
    scanf("%f", &b);
        }
    }

    else if (c < 0) {
        printf("The number c must be positive");
                        while(c<0){
                printf("Enter the third side of the triangle: ");
    scanf("%f", &c);
        }
    } else {
        perimeter = a + b + c;
        half_p = perimeter / 2;
        printf("\nPerimeter of triangle: %f\n", perimeter);

        height = ((2 * sqrt(half_p * (half_p - a) * (half_p - b) * (half_p - c))) / a);
        printf("\nHeight of triangle: %f\n", height);

        square = sqrt(half_p * (half_p - a) * (half_p - b) * (half_p - c));
        printf("\nSquare of triangle: %f\n", square);

        median = 0.5 * sqrt(2 * pow(b, 2) + 2 * pow(c, 2) - pow(a, 2));
        printf("\nMedian of triangle: %f\n", median);

        bisector = ((2 / (b + c))) * sqrt(b * c * half_p * (half_p - a));
        printf("\nBisector of triangle: %f\n", bisector);
    }

} while (1);
}
```